# how to create a txtfile with 777 permission

Tags: php

i want to create a .txt file  with the 777 permission for file creation i am using the following code

```
if(file_exists($myFile) == true) 
        {
    $err = "File Already Exist in The usrlogactity. Try Another Username";
                        }  
        else
    {
          $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");

    }
```

$file = "usrlogactity/$myFile";

```
                        $ftp_server="02.79.103.130";  

                        // set up basic connection
             $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

                        // login with username and password
        $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, "use1234", "pass123");

                // try to chmod $file to 644
            if (ftp_chmod($conn_id, 0777, $file) !== false) 
                    {  
            //echo "$file chmoded successfully to 777\n";
                                } 
                    else 
                                {  
                //echo "could not chmod $file\n";
                                }

                        // close the connection
            ftp_close($conn_id);
```

if i execute this code in server it create the file with the 644 permission ,

but gives error. how to i create the .txt file with the 777 permissiom please guide me

The error is

```
No such file or directory in usrlogactity/$myFile on line 13
```

Comment: I think you dont have permission to create file ... so fix the permission in the folder, then sure you will create

Comment: are you running `chmod` in php ?

Comment: Sigh - *what* error are you getting? Please always include the exact error message

Comment: Sorry, No such file or directory in public_html/changes/changepermission.php on line 13

Comment: What is the location of the file? Does the directory already exists?

Comment: Yes i run the chmod in php, i have writes to create a file with 777 permission though php code only i face this issue

Comment: Meena, please, provide FULL CODE, contains BOTH file creation and setting permissions, along with EXACT COPY of the error message. Instead of telling us your story in words.

Comment: You can refer this link
[http://www.stadtaus.com/en/tutorials/chmod-ftp-file-permissions.php](http://www.stadtaus.com/en/tutorials/chmod-ftp-file-permissions.php)

Comment: Plz check my edited post now i included  exact code what i am using in the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change local file permissions you have to use PHP function [chmod()](http://php.net/chmod), not using ftp for this
Doing it via FTP you're trying to access this file with ftp user, not www user, and, therefore, no success.

And, you see, how it's important **to post** your code, not **to tell** about it? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the server if your scripts are allowed to and why do you need 777 for a text file you don't execute a text file you read its 644 is all you need,

but permissions should not be changed by a script different configurations leads to completely different results,

Some servers are idiots and run Apache as root, which mean php writes a file that root owns,

Some use suExec and then your login to your account owns the file

others use Apache user to control your file

so your script could work on one and not on another if you moved the site due to the file becoming unreadable

Allso check safemode on your php install